# AES encryption / decryption gives different result for the same input, and same iv, pad & mode

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

I'm trying to make 2 apps, the first encrypt a data, and save it to a file, then the second will try to read this file and decrypt its content

I'm working with `crypto-js` library with `ionic/angular`

in the first program (encrypter) I wrote:

```
encryptTest(input: string) {
    let key = "secret";
    return crypto.AES.encrypt(input, key, {
      iv: 'aTestIvValueKey',
      mode: crypto.mode.CBC,
      padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
    }).toString();
  }
```

then I call it with:

```
this.encryptTest('hello world !')
```

it gives me on output:

> U2FsdGVkX186H1iRZM4Il+10/TS6gM7DoUaghwAZX3A=

when I try to decrypt this output in the second program, it doesn't give me the previous input: `hello world !`  but a wrong test which is:

> 68656c6c6f20776f726c642021

the second program (decrypter): has:

```
decryptTest(input: string) {
    let key = "secret";
    return crypto.AES.decrypt(input, key, {
      iv: 'aTestIvValueKey',
      mode: crypto.mode.CBC,
      padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
    }).toString();
  }
```

PS: I use the same iv, pad & mode

Comment: It's giving you the ASCII-encoded hex values of `hello world !`.  `h` = 68, `e` = 65.

Comment: 68656c6c6f20776f726c642021 actually reads hello world! it's just the hexadecimal ascii representation.

Comment: any reason no to use native crypto instead of a lib?

Comment: Bizzard, However, i asked it to convert toString(), Thanks a lot,  you saved my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what i did to resolve:

```
return crypto.AES.decrypt(input, key, {
      iv: 'aTestIvValueKey',
      mode: crypto.mode.CBC,
      padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
    }).toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: For me it is still same result as you were facing, I added utf8

Answer (score 2):

When you decrypt you get bytes, you need to pass those bytes though the correct encoding to get the words in characters.